# Visual Studio doesn't accept class implementation [C++]

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to move from Dev C++ to Visual Studio while studying C++ (since I'll have to work with the latter) but for some reason, a rather simple class implementation that perfectly works in Dev C++ creates a long list of errors in Visual Studio.

The files are simple:

- header file, for the declaration of constructors, variables etc
- cpp file, to implement said constructors, functions etc
- consoleapplication file (on visual studio), to produce the "main()" function.

stock2.h

```
#ifndef STOCK2_H_
#define STOCK2_H_
class Stock
{
public:
    Stock();
    Stock(const char* co, int n = 0, double pr = 0.0);
    ~Stock();
    void show()const;
private:
    std::string company;
    int shares;
    double share_val;
    double total_val;
};
#endif
```

stock2.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stock2.h"

Stock::Stock()  //default constructor
{
    //code
}

Stock::Stock(const char* co, int n, double pr)
{
    //code
}

Stock::~Stock()
{
    std::cout << "Stock object has been destroyed" << std::endl;
}

//Methods

void Stock::show() const
{
    //code
}
```

ConsoleApplication.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stock2.cpp"
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    const int STKS = 4;
    Stock stocks[STKS] = {
        Stock("NanoSmart", 12, 20.1),
        Stock("Boffo Objects", 200, 2.0),
        Stock(),
        Stock("Monolithic Obelisks", 130, 3.25)
    };
    cout << "Stock Holdings: \n";
    for (int st = 0; st<STKS; st++)
        stocks[st].show();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to find the solution on other questions posted here but I really can't figure out what's wrong here.
I also read that one is not supposed to #include a cpp file since the header should be the link between the main() and the cpp file itself, but if I decide to use #include stock2.H instead of .CPP in consoleapplication, then the compiler can't find the methods implementations anymore.

EDIT: In the rush i forgot to post the errors!
They're all in this form:

Error   LNK2005 
"public: void __thiscall Stock::update(double)" (?update@Stock@@QAEXN@Z) already defined in 
ConsoleApplication1.obj ConsoleApplication1 //path\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\stock2.obj

EDIT2: Since many of you are asking me about the "Solution Explorer", I better just add a screenshot to show you how it's made right now
[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting? And if the compiler (actually the linker) can't find the method implementations when you include the header file (which is the correct approach) then you have set up your project incorrectly

Comment: As you've been told, only include the header files. Your implementation files should be automatically compiled and linked if they are included in your project file. In Visual Studio, make sure all of your source files are listed in the Solution Explorer view. You can drag-drop files into this view to add them to your project if they are missing.

Comment: I just added the error I get (I completely forgot to add those!). Anyway, I used the standard set up for projects on Visual Studio so I have 2 primary folders under the Project Folder: Source Files (for all the .cpp files) and Header Files(where I stored stock2.h)

Comment: Read the messages and try to analyze them a bit. You have `ConsoleApplication1.obj` included in your app. Where does it come from?

Comment: @kn0bbulo "Stock::update(double)" You are not defining this function in your code. The code you provided is unrelated to the error message you provided. From the error message, it seems you are providing two implementations for a `update(double)` method of class `Stock`. This will happen if you include .cpp files. This is one of the main reasons you cannot include implementation files.

Comment: Have you added stock2.h and stock2.cpp to the project? You should see them both in the Solution Explorer window.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I cut out of the code many methods I implemented, otherwise the open post would've been extremely long. The error related to the "update" method is the same I get for every other constructor and method I implemented in the stock2.cpp file.

Comment: @acraig5075 I just added a screenshot to the open post. Both files are inside the Solution Explorer box

Comment: @kn0bbulo Remove all includes to .cpp files and recompile your project (Ctrl + Alt + F7).

Comment: it's `#include "stock2.h"` not `#include "stock2.cpp"`

Comment: @PeterT as I said, if I do that, then the compiler doesn't find the class nor its methods etc

Comment: Also, you said that the main file is called `ConsoleApplication.cpp`, yet your project screenshot clearly shows that it includes `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`. What's up with that? Is it `ConsoleApplication.cpp` or `ConsoleApplication1.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

You included `stock2.cpp` in your `ConsoleApplication.cpp`. This means all the code inside `stock2.cpp` is now compiled twice, and the linker shows the error message

```
Error LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall Stock::<...> already defined
```

for the now duplicated functions. Simply replace

```
#include "stock2.cpp"
```

with

```
#include "stock2.h"
```

If you get another error when doing so, please post the error message for this.